# shell scripting, run in parallel processes

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/ksh
##########################################################################
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar SocketListener.jar 8182

run_something_else

exit 0
```

SocketListener is started, and shell is waiting while SocketListener don't die.

How can I run **run_something_else** and SocketListener at the same time

Comment: Run it in the background by suffixing the command line with an `&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar SocketListener.jar 8182 &
```

add an ampersand(`&`) at the end.this will give control of the terminal to the next line and makes your `SocketListener` run in the background.

Answer (score 3):

[nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) can be used to run the process in the background as daemon.

```
nohup runsomethingelse &
```

Answer (score 1):

You could background something else:

```
nohup run_something_else &
```

`Nohup` will guarantee that sumething_else will run even if your terminal closes. So it will make it ignore `sighup`

Comment: Without the surrounding backticks, I presume?

Comment: The surrounding backticks where for the code tag :) i guess i pressed the button twice :)